# How to propagate message ceilings through all dataflow blocks?

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I wonder whether there is a way to set the max number of items/messages a queue within a dataflow block can hold (either bufferblock or queue of actionblock) and propagate such ceiling upstream to other datablocks that may feed the datablock that contains the queue, which has its maximum items it can hold, set. I guess the queues of supplying datablocks will just increase in items, correct? Is there a way to have them lock as well or would I need to implement ceilings as well for all queues of blocks that link to the block that contains the queue with ceiling?

For example I may start with a custom producing dataflow block that links to a bufferblock. This buffer block links to an action block whose queue I like to not have exceed a certain number of items in the queue. How can I prevent the queues in the producing dataflow block or bufferblock from ever storing more and more items in their own queue knowing that the last dataflow block in the chain cannot consume more items at a point in time and that the inQueue cannot accept more items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any “smart” way to do this, you just have to set `BoundedCapacity` in each block's options when you create them.

I think there are several reasons why what you're proposing wouldn't work:

1. How exactly should the block decide what its capacity should be? Just because an `ActionBlock` has a capacity of 100 doesn't mean the `BufferBlock` in front of it should have the same capacity. This is something that has to be decided by a human.
2. Blocks' options cannot be changed after creation. Doing what you want would require you to change the options.

That being said, I think that in your simple case, you could just get rid of the `BufferBlock` and send the items from the producing block directly to the `ActionBlock`.

Comment: I use the bufferblock in subclasses so that a central calling class can establish the link between a public buffer block that is contained  each in several subclasses. Any better ideas how to have one dataflow block link to and stream to another dataflow block in a different class?

Comment: I don't understand why would you need a `BufferBlock` for that. Why don't you just expose the internal block as a `ITargetBlock`?

Comment: a slightly related but different question (not sure it warrants a new question): Is there a way to flush the queues of any/all the dataflow blocks if the stream is interrupted, Ctrl+C in windows consol app, or when simply exiting the program while there are still items in some of the queues? The problem is that even though the application completely closes down, the next time I start it up it seems there are still old items from the previous run in some of the queues. I am quite perplexed by this. Is there something similar to the TPL Task CancellationToken?

Comment: I did that actually, buffer blocks was just a simplified example.

Comment: You can set a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the options of each block. But I'm not sure it would help you, there is no automatic persistence, so if it looks like there are items saying in the queues even after you restart the application, there is something else going on.

Comment: If I let the application run till it exits itself I do not have issues, but if I cancel the app through ctrl-c I am dealing with old items from the previous run. I do run a FileStream and BinaryReader within a Datablock, could it be related to that? Is it maybe that the cache or I/O buffer does not get flushed?

Comment: re your ITargetBlock comment, I tried it, but for my project I probably need to use an IPropagatorBlock because I Post items to it and use it to link to another datablock. Correct?

Comment: sorry please ignore the CancellationToken thing, I tweaked things around the dataflow blocks and believe it or not, did not manually re-build the code in VS (I was under the assumption running the code in debug mode always re-builds prior to running the code), sorry my bad.